# Python function to round to the nearest .5

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python how do you round numbers to the nearest 0.5.

For example

100.4 would round to 100.5

100.6 would round to 100.5

100.9 would round to 101

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's builtin `round` function can be used to round a number to a certain number of decimal places. By multiplying the number by 2, rounding it to no decimal places and dividing it again, we can round a number to the nearest 0.5:

```py
num = 3.46
result = round(num * 2) / 2
print(result)  # 3.5
```

As a function this is:

```py
def to_nearest_half(num):
    return round(num * 2) / 2
```

The function can also be generalised to any decimal:

```py
def to_nearest(num, decimal):
   return round(num / decimal) * decimal
```

Comment: Ok thanks this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```py
def roundhalf(x: float):
    return round(x*2)/2
```

Can be tested with

```py
for x in [100.4, 100.6, 100.9]:
    print(roundup(x))
```

The output is indeed

```
100.5
100.5
101.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to do this is to multiply by a factor that allows your fractional rounding target to be a whole number, do the rounding, and then divide that factor back out. In this case that factor is 2, because 0.5 times 2 is 1, a whole number.

```
x = 100.4
y = round(x * 2) / 2
```

To print it always using a single decimal place, you can use `str.format()`.

```
'{:.1f}'.format(round(x * 2) / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be this:

```
def myRound(x):
    if 0 <= (x % int(x)) <= 0.25 or 0.75 <= (x % int(x)) <= 0.99:
        return round(x)
    else:
        return int(x) + 0.5
```

Explanation:

1. You only care about the decimal part, so first you need to check if it's close enough to the integer - if so, use the standard round method.
2. If it's not - then it's closest to 0.5, so you round it up (int(x) will cut the decimal part) and just add 0.5

I assumed you want anything below .25 to be rounded as 0, anything above .75 to be rounded as 1, and everything in between to be rounded as .5
You can modify the bounds.