# Ceil any number in python this way - 2.3, 2.1, 1.9, 2.6. to 2.5, 2.5, 2, 3 i.e. addition leads to addition of .5 or 1 whichever is closest

Tags: python, ceil

Default ceiling doesn't work this way.
Ceil should work in this way -
Example 2 -
3.1, 4.5, 5.9
after ceiling -  3.5, 4.5, 6

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70367402/python-function-to-round-to-the-nearest-5) answer to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

```
def roundOffnumber (number):
 return (math.ceil(number*2))/2
```